# Functions in loop

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and I have a trouble in using `for()` loop.

I have a data frame `inv` that I want to calculate the number of individuals per species by using a loop.
The data frame includes 48 plots and now I want to make a rarefaction curve for each plot based on individuals

I can make it for a single plot, for example:

```
P01_subset <- inv[inv$plot_ID == 'P01',]

P01_n <- P01_subset %>%                        #get number of individual per species
  group_by(same_sp_as) %>% 
  summarise(individuals = n())

count_1 <- as.numeric(c(P01_n.$individuals))   #Covert abundance frequency counts to species abundance data
invaded <- list(invaded = count_1)
output <- iNEXT(invaded, q=0, datatype = 'abundance')
ggiNEXT(output, type = 1)
```

However, I can not calculate for all plot by using a loop.

My code is here:

```
plot_re <- list()
inv_list <- split(inv, inv$plot_ID)

for(i in length(inv_list)){    
  plot_ind[[i]] <- inv_list[[i]] %>% group_by(same_sp_as) %>% summarize(individuals = n())
  plot_re <- (plot_ind[[i]])
}
```

It got an error: **Can't assign column 48 in a tibble with 2 columns.**

I am trying to fix it but it doesn't work.
Please check it out and help me to understand what I did incorrectly.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your [data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us reproduce the error? Also in your code I see 3 things that may be causing an issue. Your for loop isn't defined over a vector so there it's only run once with `i=length(inv_list)`. I don't see `plot_ind` defined outside of the for loop. And your last line in the for loop assignes `plot_ind[[i]]` to the variable `plot_re` not just a single element in the list.

Comment: @cookesd thank you for helping me. 
I would like to send an image below.

Comment: Do you need a loop to get the number of species in each group? You could do that in two ways using `dplyr`. (1) 1iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize(N = n())` or (2)`iris %>% count(Species, sort = T)`

Comment: @user3585829 thank man. I already tried them before, but I want to get the number of individuals per species per plot.

Comment: Add the second variable to your count as well. E.g., `iris %>% count(Species, Plot, sort = T)`